# svn hangs trying to access repo from osx mavericks 1.7.10

Tags: svn, osx-mavericks

I have an svn 1.7.9 server, but for some reason my new iMac that is running svn 1.7.10 just hangs trying to get at the repo like:

```
  svn list svn://69.225.X.X:8080
```

I can telnet to the port just fine and access the repo from an older Mac and Windows ... no problem.  Any ideas how to debug?

Update1: This is a complete mystery, I found that subversion 1.6 was on the drive, even pointing to that it is hanging!

Update2: Mystery continues.  I compiled svn 1.8.5 and guess what...it hangs!

**How can these hang, but telnet connects fine?**

Update 3: More digging. The server is running svnserve/svn 1.8 (from TortoiseSVN). It seems Windows boxes running Tortoise 1.8 work fine.  Both MACs don't connect, one hangs and you can't control-C, another hangs, you control-C and you get "Address already in use" which makes no sense.  These are both running svn 1.7.X, but as I said I **compiled 1.8.X and it hangs too**!

Update 4: A co-worker is running OSX 9.1 and just (like I did) built 1.8.5 from sources and he can connect!! Now I have no clue what the difference might be.

Update 5: The problem (must) stem from running svnserve on port 8080 on a windows box.  Not sure why everyone else works, but changing svnserve to 3690 works !!  I would really like to know why this is happening though.

Comment: Update.  This is bizzare, the problem only happens when svnserve (on windows) is running on 8080. If it is running on 3690 it works fine!!!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your server runs 'svnserve' on port 8080?

Svnserve usually runs on the standard port 3690, while port 8080 is usually used for http via apache.

So I wouldn't be surprised if you have better luck if you use:

```
svn ls http://69.225.X.X:8080
```

Comment: Yes, I can telnet to 8080.  In fact I have other clients that are connecting just fine to the server on 8080.

Comment: Yes, you can telnet to port 8080. But what do you get when you type something? Is it something like `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">` or `( success ( 2 2 ( ) ( edit-pipeline svndiff1 absent-entries commit-revprops depth log-revprops atomic-revprops partial-replay ) ) )`?

Comment: Connection closed by foreign host.